# Наследование + event broadcasting

Tags: c#, wpf

Заранее прошу прощения за невнятный заголовок, не придумал как лучше объяснить.

Итак, у меня есть набор WPF-control (кастомных, делаю сам).

Нужно, чтобы каждый из них мог как посылать, так и "получать" события, стало быть, напрашивается интерфейс:

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object parameter);

public interface IMyCommand
{
    event MyEventHandler OnSend;
    event MyEventHandler OnReceive;
}
```

Вроде как все логично, но нужно знать, кто посылает события, поэтому расширим делегат на тип UserControl:

```
public enum MyControlType
{
    A,
    B,
    etc..
};

public delegate void MyEventHandler(MyControlType type, object parameter);
```

И все, опять-таки, логично. Но, так как UserControl'ы - часть WPF приложения, нужно при старте пройти по `VisualTree`и подписаться на каждый из них.

Я подумал, что в этом нет ничего сложного (и с точки зрения архитектуры правда нет) - создадим базовый класс или интерфейс, пробежимся по VisualTree, и если тип соответствует - подпишемся.

И вот тут появилась проблема: так как UserControl в WPF - это partial-классы, они не поддерживают multiple inheritance (что, опять-таки, понятно и логично).

Я попытался сделать code trick:

```
public class MyBaseClass: UserControl
{
}

public partial class MyControl : MyBaseClass
{
}
```

И это не "жрет" даже VS 2019.

Думаю, ок - мы же можем наследоваться от `DependencyObject` и искать по `VisualTree` хрестоматийным методом, которые все, кто умеет гуглить, используют:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                 yield return (T)child;

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                   yield return childOfChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Но этот метод выдает `Count = 0`

Возможно, я изначально не так спроектировал? Буду благодарен любым советам.

Comment: @Igor, спасибо за исправление опечатки :)

Comment: Вам стоит понять одну простейшую вещь - UserControl в WPF - это View, не больше! То есть у него не должно быть какой то логики по работе там с объектами или чем то еще, лишь вывод в UI. Разделите все на слои, сделайте ViewModel/Model слои и тогда сможете уже делать то, что вам нужно.

Comment: `у меня есть набор WPF-control` ... `чтобы каждый из них мог как посылать, так и "получать" события` ... `нужно при старте пройти по VisualTreeи подписаться на каждый из них` ====> [`Routed Events`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview) ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я это прекрасно понимаю. Думаю, из вопроса понятно, что проблема заключается в том, что нужно "довинтить" имеющийся код, а не реализовать новую архитектуру по MVVM. Если из вопроса неясно - sorry :)

Comment: @tym32167, Вы сейчас, кажется, сделали из меня идиота в самом лучшем смысле :) То, что нужно. Заработался :( Спасибо!

Comment: @МаксЖуков на здоровье :)